# Set default user session to XFCE4

Tags: lightdm, xfce

How do I set the default user session to XFCE4?

I have tried:

`sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults --session xfce`

`sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults --session xfce4`

`sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults --session xubuntu-desktop`

I am using xRDP and do not have access to the normal greeter.

Answer (score 11):

I created file `~/.xsession` with a one liner `xfce4-session`.

Answer (score 4):

It works with `xfce4-session`.

```
sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults --session xfce4-session
```

Comment: /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults seems to be missing in ubuntu 14.04 :(

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 16.04.1, 
I installed xubuntu-default-settings and it works fine. Now I can login in xfce by default.

```
sudo apt install xubuntu-default-settings
```